# Spring configured JMS Listener Idle time out

Tags: java, spring-jms

I have a Spring configured JMS listener and If the messages not receive for few hours (if it idle without receiving any messages) it will not pick any messages after that. Could some one kindly explain what can be the issue here.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Don't you think the obvious issue is that the queue connection is getting closed after a certain amount of time? There must be a threshhold on the time limit on the inactivity period of the queue connection.

The configuration can be for Spring or for the webserver/application server on which this is deployed.

Comment: Its just a java service there are no any servers . I'm just wandering whether Spring has that kind of configuration.

Comment: ConnectionTTL property can help you out, if you can set it.. This is basically the Time to Live for a connection in JMSConnectionFactory